# Spring Boot 3.2.3 no longer logs Http11InputBuffer

Tags: spring-boot

I find that starting from Spring Boot `3.2.3`, below logging configuration no longer works - It does not print incoming request details.

I don't find anything from the [release changelog of Spring Boot 3.2.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.2.3).

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer: DEBUG
```

A sample log message that comes from previous Spring Boot versions:

```
<timestamp> [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer (DirectJDKLog.java:173) - Received [POST /api/123 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 16

{"value": "foo"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings seem to have changed a bit since the Tomcat library was recently updated.
Try the 'trace' level.

[application.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl9Lz.png)